# Show MSTest progress in GatedCheckIn

Tags: c#, mstest

We are using GatedCheckins and after building the change on the server several tests are executed. We want a possibility to show the test progress in the GatedCheckin window (below the "Run MS Test for Test Assemblies" message). Is there any way to pipe test output to the GatedCheckin window?

[image]